# Database name in connection with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost

I'm working on developing a website through Dreamweaver with html, php, and mySQL, and I wanna connect it to the localhost, so I installed easyPHP and added an alias in the local files with the name saadstore and the directory of the folder
However, when I run my code it displays an error when the database name is selected!
Instead if I run a page that doesn't interact with links and other pages in my site (doesn't need connection) it works just fine!
Here's the code:

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="saadstore";

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass")or die("Could not connect to mySQL"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("no database");
?>
```

when I save and open the file from the localhost I get "no database"
I'm kinda new to this so .. any help?

Comment: `mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass)` AND `mysql_select_db($db_name)` Remove the double quotes.

Comment: why did you tag sql-server-2008? you are connecting to a MySQL database, not SQL Server. The tags "sql-server-2008", "web", and "connection", do not belong here.

Comment: @aldrin27 works either way, just as long as they're not single quotes.

Comment: @AcidReign Again I'm new to this :) can u explain what u just wrote?

Comment: @MohamedM.Saad do you mean my comment asking why you put irrelevant tags? This question is only about "php" and "mysql" the rest of the tags do not belong on this question. (the tag "connection" is just ambiguous and unhelpful IMO)

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:-

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="saadstore";

$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass)or die("Could not connect to mySQL"); 
$selected = mysql_select_db($db_name, ,$conn)or die("no database");
?>
```

At last

```
  mysql_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_* functions are deprecated/obsolete, and will soon be removed from PHP entirely, please don't use them.

Instead you should use PDO: http://php.net/pdo

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it says "Unknown database 'saadstore'" so how do I know the name of my database if it's not the name of the alias I created in the localhost?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "alias I created in the localhost". The "database" name (also called Schema) has to exist in the MySQL server you are connecting to.

Comment: Well, I simply installed easyPHP and through it I could enter http://127.0.0.1/home/ and make a database, so if there's another way to put my project in a localhost, what is it?

Comment: Well it sounds like you did not actually create a schema in MySQL called "saadstore". I don't know anything about easyPHP, but when it comes to managing my MySQL server I prefer to use MySQL Workbench: https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/  (it is free)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try "mysqli_connect" Like that way :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use AcidReign solution, it's using PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_*. 
I also don't know anything about easyPHP, but realize you actually don't have a database called saadstore. 
Then, access on your browser the adress **http://localhost/phpmyadmin** it's gonna ask you the username and password that according to you the user is **root** and you haven't any password.

After you log in you will see a screen like the below:

[image]

On the left side you can see all your databases, if the name **saadstore** is not there, then you don't have the database and need to create them.
To do so, you must go to DataBase tab and put the name of your database(saadstore) and the Collation, which I recommend to put utf8_general_ci.

[image]

Now you have your database and may create your tables.